# how to return TByteDynArray in SqlServerMethod DataSnap Server

Tags: delphi, client-server, delphi-xe, datasnap, rad-studio

I have a DataSnap Server with a Server method like this:

```
function TServerMethods1.Get_Excel_History(key: string): TByteDynArray;
```

Now, on the DataSnap Client using TSQLServerMethod, I successfully connect to the server in Design Mode, and I'm sending the request to Server and successfully receiver the data but can not read the output parameter.

```
  M.SqlServerMethod1.Close;
  M.ClientDataSet_All.Close;
  M.SqlServerMethod1.ServerMethodName:='TServerMethods1.Get_XML_History';
  M.SqlServerMethod1.Params.ParamByName('key').Value:=Edit1.Text;
  M.SqlServerMethod1.ExecuteMethod;


  ByteDynArray_Result:=M.SqlServerMethod1.Params.ParamByName('ReturnParameter').As???????;
```

How can i read the type of TByteDynArray?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `M`? Why not call the method directly via the proxy?

Comment: Why not return it as a stream?  And why is the ServerMethodName 'Get_XML_History' but you refer to `TServerMethods1.Get_Excel_History(key: string)`?

Comment: I have added an answer to a very similar question in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393907/convert-tbytedynarray-to-tstream-in-delphi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TByteDynArray is not a valid DataSnap parameter. The list of allowed parameter types depends on the Delphi version and is documented here: [Exposing DataSnap Server Methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Exposing_DataSnap_Server_Methods).
For Delphi 10.2 Tokyo this is:

```
Boolean
SmallInt
Integer
Int64
Single
Double
AnsiString
String
TDBXTime
TDBXDate
TJSONValue and all descendents
TDBXWideStringValue
TDBXAnsiStringValue
TDBXUInt8Value
TDBXInt8Value
TDBXInt16Value
TDBXInt32Value
TDBXInt64Value
TDBXSingleValue
TDBXDoubleValue
TDBXBcdValue
TDBXTimeValue
TDBXDateValue
TDBXTimeStampValue
TDBXBooleanValue
TDBXReaderValue
TDBXStreamValue
```

A valid alternative could be stream or JSON.

Comment: How get Json from TByteDynArray ?