# Convert TByteDynArray to TStream in Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi

How to convert TByteDynArray to TStream in Delphi and save it in data base

Comment: Why do you need to use TByteDynArray in the first place, if you are getting your data from MS Sql Server?

Comment: Can you mention your Delphi version, please?

Comment: Which database client library do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save it on a Stream, create a MemoryStream and write your ByteDynArray on it :

```
  ResultStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  ResultStream.Write(MyByteDynArray, Length(MyByteDynArray));
  ResultStream.Position := 0;
```

To save it on a database, create a query object (FDQuery, ADOQuery, ...) with a parametrized SQL statement :

```
update MyTable set MyColumn = :Data where Id = 1;
```

and load your Stream on that parameter :

```
MyQuery.ParamByName('Data').LoadFromStream(ResultStream);
```

Comment: To avoid copying, you could use the protected `SetPointer` method to directly use the array data, or in some XE+ versions of Delphi, just use `TBytesStream` which does the same.

Comment: Note that the `Write()` overload shown in the answer was introduced in XE3, for earlier versions use `Write(MyByteDynArray[0], ...)` or `Write(PByte(MyByteDynArray)^, ...)` instead. And `TBytesStream` was introduced in D2009.